# Is there a workaround to the version limitation for QGIS resource sharing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am using Qgis version 3.0.2. After downloading the QGIS Resource sharing plugin (by akbargumbira) I noticed it's only supported for the versions 2.4-2.99. Is there a workaround to use it on 3.0.2 (haven't been able to find any comparable tools to import icons etc.), or am I better off downloading an older QGIS version?

Answer (score 1):

The *Resource Sharing* plugin version 0.6.0 (available since 4 December 2018) was the first version to support QGIS 3. Some issues (https://github.com/akbargumbira/qgis_resources_sharing/issues), but it is still quite useful for sharing your resources with the community.

**EDIT:**
As of today (7 February 2020), there has been an additional update ([v0.7.0](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing/version/0.7.0/)), which removes the Experimental QGIS Plugin flag, merges some pending pull-requests, and improves behavior when working against incompatible versions of QGIS.

```
0.7.0 - Flip experimental flag
      - Merge PR from havatv (avoid breaking on incompatible versions)
```